# Can we preserve the timestamp of parent directory after modifying the files inside it?

Tags: linux, directory, date, timestamps

I have a folder structure:

```
/home/us3r/scripts
```

I've some scripts inside the `scripts` folder.
Now, i want to preserve the timestamp of the `scripts` folder even if someone does a `vim` and saves any of the files inside the `scripts` folder.
Or do not allow anyone to edit/save the files inside the `scripts` folder.

Either way,is there any way out?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you want to keep the modification time of the directory the same when people save files in the directory, or do you want to prevent people from saving files in the directory?

Comment: @G-Man: yeah, you can say that i want to prevent people from modifying/saving files in that directory. Basically, they should not be allowed to do any `vi` or `vim` on any of the files inside `scripts` folder. Thanks!!!

Comment: OK, that seems to be totally different from what you said in the actual question.  Please [edit] the question title & body to say what you mean.

Comment: @G-Man: I've edited my question.Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set immutable attribute on the directory

```
sudo chattr +i /home/us3r/scripts
```

This would prevent any changes of data or metadata of that folder and files inside of it.

However, this also means you would not be able to create, modify or change permissions, ownership or attributes of that folder and files inside of it.

Comment: would this work only if i'm the `root` user?

Comment: @A.K yes. Only with `root` permissions, i.e as `root` user or with `sudo`